# I used the std::string::substr method inside the if block but if block isn't working

Tags: c++

There's a string with the word "WUB" in it, and I need to eliminate this word from the string.
So I used the substring method inside the if block so that while traversing the loop, if block can catch the WUB and instead print 1

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s="WUBhello";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    
        if(s.substr(i,i+2)=="WUB"){
            cout<<"1 ";
            i+=2;
        }
        else{
            cout<<s[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

I'm expecting it will print only "hello" , but it's printing "WUBhello"

Comment: Rethink your logic in the loop again please.

Comment: When an `if` statement is not doing what you expect, a good first step in debugging is to verify the condition. What is `s.substr(i,i+2)`? Try `std::cout << s.substr(i,i+2) << '\n';` before the statement. Also a sanity check: `std::cout << (s.substr(i,i+2)=="WUB") << '\n';`

Comment: Tangential: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3840170>

Answer (score 0):

**1. The issues in your code:**

There are several issues, some bugs and some bad practices (see side notes below).
To begin with, [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) 's second parameter is `count` - i.e. the number of characters. So in your case it should simply be `3`. You also don't check that `i < s.length()-3` before using `substr`.
Then the whole logic of your loop is flawed. Using a debuggers will help you to get more insight. See: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

---

**2. A better approach:**

If you want to remove a substring from a string, you can do the following:

1. Use [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to find the substring.
2. Then use [`std::string::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) to remove it.

**Code example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "WUBhello";
    std::string toRemove = "WUB";

    // Find the substring:
    auto pos = str.find(toRemove);
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        // Remove it:
        str.erase(pos, toRemove.length());
    }

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
hello
```

If you want to remove multiple occurances of the substring, you can apply similar logic in a loop:

```
// Find the 1st occurance substring:
auto pos = str.find(toRemove);
while (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    // Remove it:
    str.erase(pos, toRemove.length());
    // Find the next one:
    pos = str.find(toRemove);
}
```

**Some side notes:**

1. [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)
2. [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::stringstream` too.

> Note: Do check the function signature of any standard library function before using it. `std::substr`'s second argument is length of substring.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::string remove_substring(const std::string& s, const std::string& key)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); )
    {
        if (s.substr(i, key.length()) == key)
        {
            i += key.length();
        }
        else 
        {
            ss << s[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}
int main()
{
    const std::string s = "WUBhello";
    const std::string key = "WUB";
    std::cout << remove_substring(s, key);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

The second argument of `std::string::substr` is exclusive, so it should be `i+3`. Also, even when the logic is correct, it will print "1 hello".

Comment: The second parameter is a count or number of characters.